# Join only if field is more than zero

Tags: sql, database, join

Instead of making 2 queries could I somehow just join persons if houses.owner_id is greater than zero?

```
SELECT * FROM houses 
INNER JOIN persons ON persons.id = houses.owner_id 
WHERE houses.id = id
```

Comment: Do you want the result to contain houses with owner_id = 0?

Comment: Can't you just do `WHERE houses.id = id AND houses.owner_id > 0` ?

Comment: I probably should have written that as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: What is `WHERE houses.id = id` supposed to do? It will cause an ambiguous name reference as both tables have an `id` and it looks as though the intended join condition is `persons.id = houses.owner_id` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Move the condition into the join's condition:

```
SELECT * FROM houses 
JOIN persons ON persons.id = houses.owner_id 
    AND houses.owner_id > 0
WHERE houses.id = id
```

This will only join if owner_id > 0.

---

This query is a little odd, because you're not using the joined data.

Comment: agreed - funny - but maybe it means 'houses owned by a person'

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM houses 
INNER JOIN persons ON persons.id = houses.owner_id 
WHERE houses.id = id AND houses.owner_id > 0
```

Not sure why an owner_id would be smaller than 0? Maybe a bad database design.  Also `SELECT *` is considered bad practice, try to explicitly state your columns.

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass it in as a where condition?

```
SELECT * FROM houses 
INNER JOIN persons ON persons.id = houses.owner_id 
WHERE houses.id = id AND houses.owner_id > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use count of house.owner_id > 0. Having and group by clause is needed. Also, this is not a good SQL design.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are probably what you want, but, for completeness, you might want to adjust the `JOIN` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM houses 
INNER JOIN persons ON persons.id = houses.owner_id AND houses.owner_id > 0
WHERE houses.id = id
```